# Python and Google API: How to avoid referring to empty array when uploading CSVs

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

This script is doing few things:

1. Lists all CSV in my local folder (CSVtoGD)
2. Deletes files in Google Drive folder which names are the same to those files in local folder (CSVtoGD) (To do this I have to get the spreadsheetID of files in GD)
3. Uploads new files from CSVtoGD to Google Drive folder.

Script is working but I have a problem when there is new CSV in local folder ("CSVtoGD") which has never been sent to Google Drive. In this situation the script is uploading the new file but just after that I got "kernel crashed" error. I know that the problem is because I am trying to refer to array that is empty.

```
if fname[1] == "csv":
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath) # - that where the problem is. I have to create some 
new "IF" to avoid the script from getting spreadsheetId 
from file which has never been sent to GD
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
```

I have no idea how to achieve that. Could someone give me a hint?

Full script:

```
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=gc.auth)
folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi'  


def getSpreadsheetId(filename, filePath):
    q = "name='" + filename + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false"
    res = service.files().list(q=q, fields="files(id)", corpora="allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    items = res.get("files", [])
    if not items:
        print("No files found.")
        
        file_metadata = {
            "name": filename,
            "parents": [folder_id],
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        }
        media = MediaFileUpload(filePath + "/" + filename + ".csv")
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
        id = file.get("id")
        print("File was uploaded. The file ID is " + id)
        exit()
    return items[0]["id"]


filePath = '/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD'
os.chdir(filePath)

files = os.listdir()
for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath) # - that where the problem is. I have to create some new "IF" to avoid the script from getting spreadsheetId from file which has never been sent to GD
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.create(fname[0], folder_id)
        content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
        gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

Full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zw/12ns4dw96zb34ktc_vfn0zp80000gp/T/ipykernel_97950/981501572.py in <module>
     38     fname = filename.split(".")
     39     if fname[1] == "csv":
---> 40         oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath)
     41         print(oldSpreadsheetId)
     42         sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)

/var/folders/zw/12ns4dw96zb34ktc_vfn0zp80000gp/T/ipykernel_97950/981501572.py in getSpreadsheetId(filename, filePath)
     27         exit()
     28 
---> 29     return items[0]["id"]
     30 
     31 

IndexError: list index out of range
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

EDIT: I think I know how to repair this bug:

```
filePath = '/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD'
os.chdir(filePath)

files = os.listdir()
for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath)
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.create(fname[0], folder_id)
        content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
        gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

How to make this part of script checks if there is file in filePath (local folder) and in the same time in Google Drive and then get oldspreadsheetID. Because it trys to get oldspreadsheetID from all files in Google Drive but based on filenames from local folder, but in local folder there are files which are not yet in Google Drive, that's why the error occurs. Some hints? I need just one IF ( IF there is not file in local folder filepath, do not get oldspreadsheetID)

Comment: Although I also asked in your previous question, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `but I have a problem when there is new CSV in local folder ("CSVtoGD") which has never been sent to Google Drive. In this situation the script is uploading the new file but just after that I got "kernel crashed" error.`. So can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: 1. I have CSV in local folder (CSVtoGD)
2. I have some CSV files already in Google Drive
3. I want to upload new file from local folder which has never been sent to GD
4. I have this error.

Comment: try this. copy some CSV in local folder and rename the file as "testing" and then try to run the script. This error will occur.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, apart from the modification suggested by Tanaike, I cannot reproduce this behavior. If the file exists in Drive, it will retrieve its id on `items[0]["id"]`. If it doesn't, it will upload the local file to Drive. In any case I can see the error you referenced.

Comment: well it is uploading new CSV from local folder which has never been sent to Drive but just after that I got this kernel crash.. As far as I know it is caused because I am trying to get value from empty array

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From `EDIT: I think I know how to repair this bug:`, I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad about it. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I have to study more and more.

Comment: About your edit, I think your script should work in the sense that, if it finds files in Drive with the right name it will return the ID, but if it doesn't find it, it will create the file and return its ID. So in both cases it will return a file ID. That's what I got when I tested your script. Therefore, I cannot understand nor reproduce your issue here.